# Wcf Rest Service to upload a file with pause and resume functionality

Tags: android, wcf, file-upload

i am trying to create a wcf rest service to upload files to the server from **Android** mobile. for that purpose i created the following rest service

**Code;**

```
byte[] buff = new byte[10485760];
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\FileUpload\\" + "filename", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    }
                }
```

now i want to add a pause and resume functionality to this service. i read some where that with the help of content-range-hedaer we can inquire the no.of bytes uploaded to server from android mobile.
can any one provide me a simple upload rest service where i can pause and resume the upload utility.
please help me in doing this pause and resume functionality in my wcf rest service.

and i want to use this rest service from my android mobile application.

**my android code:**

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.44/Service1.svc/upload");
                  InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                            new FileInputStream(new File(picturePath)), -1);
                    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
                    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```